# Class Inheritance, How to add fields to a variable already set in a parent class

Tags: python

I am trying to add information to a (parent) variable from a subclass.
I have tried it with self,super and I think this example shows what i really want to go on 
I want ProfileCreateForm to simply add fields to `fields`.  the first class shows the syntax error that i can't get right despite a couple days of searching

```
class ProfileCreateForm(Turtle_BaseInfoForm):
#fields += Turtle_BaseInfoForm.fields ('bio',
#       )
class Meta:
    model = Profile

class Turtle_BaseInfoForm(Turtle_Form):

    fields = (      "name",
                    "tags",
                    "contact_name",
                    "email",
                    "phone",
                    "address",
                    "city",
                    "state",
                    "code",
                    "country",
                    "image",

                    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
class ProfileCreateForm(Turtle_BaseInfoForm):
    fields = Turtle_BaseInfoForm.fields + ('bio',)
```